# FB.login() after FB.getLoginStatus() being blocked on Safari

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have some images that I want users to be able to post to their Facebook page when they click one of several buttons on my webpage.

```html
<script>
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
{
  if ( response && response.status == 'connected' )
  {
    postPhotosToFacebook();
  }
  else
  {
    FB.login(function(response)
    {
      if ( response && response.status == 'connected' )
      {
        postPhotosToFacebook();
      }
    },
    {
      scope: 'publish_actions'
    });
  }
}, true);
</script>
```

It's very simple code. It checks to see if the user is logged in. If yes, then it posts the pictures to Facebook. If not logged in, then it runs `FB.login()`, which makes a popup, asking the user to login to Facebook and give appropriate permissions to the app. After the login is complete, if the user successfully logged in and approved the permissions, then the app does the same as above, it posts the photos to Facebook.

The `FB.login()` popup appears to be blocked on most browsers though. Why is this?

Some methods I've seen suggest that you simply check to see if the user is logged in when they load the page. But this isn't going to work properly in all cases because a user can easily switch browser tabs to Facebook and login/logout. So then back on your web app page, it might think you are connected/disconnected when really the opposite is true.

So I HAVE to check the login status every time I want to post something and give the user the option to login if they are not. If I forgo the `FB.getLoginStatus()` and simply run `FB.login()` if the user wasn't logged in when loading the page, if they switch to Facebook, then login, then come back to the web app page, when they click the button, it will try to run `FB.login()` but you will get a Javascript error cause the user is already logged in now.

How do you get around this problem?

Comment: have u found any solution for this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling the asynchronous method `FB.getLoginStatus()`, just check to see that `FB.getUserID()` is not null, undefined, or 0.

```js
var userID = FB.getUserID();
if(!!userID){
   //user is logged in
} else {
   //user is not logged in so call
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `FB.getUserId()` is only accurate when the page first loads. If you log out of Facebook separately after your page has loaded, then `FB.getUserId()` still shows you as being logged in...